# How I can change format of list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently writing my thesis. I would like to change format of list of figures.
I need my list of figures to be numbered in parentheses, i.e.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal compilable code example (MWE) to reproduce your current state.

Comment: I use \documentclass{article} and package tocloft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're already loading the `tocloft` package, I suggest you provide the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\mdseries\Large} % optional
\renewcommand\cftfigindent{0pt}  % no indentation
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{(}   % prefix "(" before figure number
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{)} % affix ")" after figure number
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional -- for Times-like font

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\mdseries\Large} % optional
\renewcommand\cftfigindent{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{(}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{)}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Three-dimensional graph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```