# formatting list of figures - tocloft package didn't work

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

This is what I have:

[image]

And what I want: (hyphen between number and caption)

[image]

I found out about the tocloft package from these two questions below, but it didn't work for me. I'm using a customized class (not created by me), so it's hard to say exaclty which parameter is causing some incompatibility.

[How I can change format of list of figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397308/how-i-can-change-format-of-list-of-figures)

[List of Figures - how to add caption label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/list-of-figures-how-to-add-caption-label)

Any idea how I could solve this, preferably without using the tocloft package?

Let me know what details are necessary.

Comment: Something is already modifying the LOF: Figura (or Figure) is not standard.  If you can find out what is responsible for that change...

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but typographically, it should be an emdash or an endash, not a  hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code. What class are you using? What package(s) are you using? What you have shown is not regular LaTeX output. What did you try with `tocloft`?

Below is an MWE based on the `article` class and the `tocloft` package that gives you the LoF that you are after.

```
% tocloftprob.tex  SE 562533
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% change LoF title and position
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST DE ILUSTRACOES}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
% change appearance of figure number
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figura } % put this before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{ ---} % put this after number
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5.2em} % need more space for changed number represenation

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps some of the above is irrevelant as you seem to have managed (I do not know how) to change the title and its position for the LoF.